# How to make Eclipse CDT's Linux GCC toolchain resolve C++ standard library headers?

Tags: eclipse, c++, c, eclipse-cdt

In Ubuntu 12.04 LTS I installed the Eclipse CDT plugin and opened the new hello world project to just test everything out. When I was creating the project, I chose the only toolchain: "Linux GCC"

When the project is created, however, it says that

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlb>
```

are unresolved. Thus, lines with `cout` and `endl` can't be used and it cannot find `std`.

`using namespace std;` is also causing problems.

How can I get my `#include` directives for standard library headers recognized, to support code using the `std` namespace?

Comment: Do these errors persist even after you do `Project` > `Build All`?

Comment: Mayne this is a stupid question but did you create a new project specifically as a C++ project rather than a C project?

Answer (score 4):

If you had the same issue I did, I suspect that your project builds but code-completion / code highlighting fails? I've just found some notes that may be useful. Here's what I did:

- Project->Properties
- C/C++ General
- Paths and Symbols
- select the appropriate language
- Click "Add" and add the compiler-version specific directories

For language 'GNU C++' I added:

```
  /usr/include
  /usr/include/c++/4.6
  /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits
  /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu
  /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits
  /usr/include/c++/4.6/debug
  /usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu
  /usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu/bits
```

For "GNU C" I added:

```
  /usr/include
  /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu
  /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits
```

TBH, I don't think all the directories above are actually required (you could probably remove the 'bits' directories) but the list above worked for me at the time.

I am now using Eclipse Indigo (version 3.7.2) from eclipse.org and it automatically finds and adds the correct include directories. The list is different for me:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6
/usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu
/usr/include/c++/4.6/backward
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/include
/usr/local/include
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/include-fixed
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu
/usr/include
```

Clearly, only add the include directories that actually exist on your system ;-)

Comment: Well, this doesn't work for me - although I'm actually on Debian Stretch 64-bit. But I did adapt your suggestions to my platform.