# How to set an include system directory in the Eclipse Platform

Tags: 12.04, eclipse

From the 'Ubuntu Software Center', I have installed Eclipse Platform Version: 3.7.2. and 'eclipse-cdt C/C++ Development Tools'. 
In the eclipse Samples at Eclipse.org, I see only these for java, not for C/C++ as I need. Therefore I have downloaded  hello-2.7.tar.xz from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/hello/, unpacked it into my eclipse directory and made a new C Linux project for it.
Its 'Project... Build all' does not find the file from the line

```
#include <config.h>
```

of the hello.c file as you can see from the listing

```
  
**** Build of configuration Debug for project hello-2.7 ****

make all 
Building file: ../src/hello.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/hello.d" -MT"src/hello.d" -o "src/hello.o" "../src/hello.c"
../src/hello.c:19:20: fatal error: config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [src/hello.o] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****
```

. Please advise me how to set an include system directory in the Eclipse Platform. (In its help, I have tried searching for it; but it only started an indexing that shows '0% complete' even after several hours. The CPU is

```
Ubuntu
Release 12.04 (precise) 32—bit
Kernel Linux 3.5.0-39-generic
GNOME 3.4.2
Hardware
Memory: 994.9 MiB
Processor: Intel Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.00GHz x 2
System Status
Available disk space 39.4 GiB
```

.) At all, does the line

```
#include <config.h>
```

mean the same in Linux as I am used to from Windows and not a further file from the GNU pages?
   Thanks!

Comment: According to http://askubuntu.com/questions/150139/how-to-make-eclipse-cdts-linux-gcc-toolchain-resolve-c-standard-library-heade?rq=1 I have found five directories, usr/include/i386-linux-gnu among others, but the config.h file is in none of them.

Comment: After I have got 2 negative votes, I have completed the example lines. And started to search what does Autoconf mean with the GNU sources.

Comment: Close-voter(s): *How* is this not about Ubuntu?